# python loop through files

Tags: python, loops

I have a python code that is pasted below. It works fine for what I need to do. You can notice that I load in a single dump file. How can I loop through all dump files that have the same ending pattern of *.dump and have each new file just add a new column of data to the output file? Essentially I want to add a loop so I do not have to manually re-write the code for each dump file.

```
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.data import *
from ovito.modifiers import *
import numpy as np

node = import_file("../200eV.dump",multiple_frames = True)

# Perform Wigner-Seitz analysis:
ws = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(
    per_type_occupancies = True, 
    eliminate_cell_deformation = True)
ws.reference.load("../../../WS_Ref/ws.dump")
node.modifiers.append(ws)

# Define a modifier function that selects sites of type A=1 which
# are occupied by exactly one atom of type B=2.
def modify(frame, input, output):

    # Retrieve the two-dimensional Numpy array with the site occupancy numbers.
    occupancies = input.particle_properties['Occupancy'].array

    # Get the site types as additional input:
    site_type = input.particle_properties.particle_type.array

    # Calculate total occupancy of every site:
    total_occupancy = np.sum(occupancies, axis=1)

    # Set up a particle selection by creating the Selection property:

    selection1 = (site_type == 1) & (occupancies[:,0] == 0) & (occupancies[:,1] == 0)

    output.attributes['Ca_Vac'] = np.count_nonzero(selection1)


# Insert Python modifier into the data pipeline.
node.modifiers.append(PythonScriptModifier(function = modify))

# Let OVITO do the computation and export the number of identified 
# antisites as a function of simulation time to a text file:
export_file(node, "defects_200.txt", "txt", 
    columns = ['Timestep', 'Ca_Vac'],
    multiple_frames = True)
```

Comment: `glob.glob('/*.dump')` shall return an iterable that would yield(can't remember if generator or list or tuple) the files that ends with `.dump` in the given relative path.

Comment: any chance you could show me how to add that to the code?

Comment: You have two different *.dump directories, which one do you want to loop through, and since I don't what is mutable and what's not in that code, if you tell me which directory to loop and what is gonna be the loop body, happy to write it for you.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan the second dump file, ws.dump, should never change. I want to loop through the eV.dump files. Sorry, I should have been clearer

Comment: Something as simple as passing the filename as an argument to your script could solve your problem - then you would be able to use tools like `xargs` to handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from ovito.data import *
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.modifiers import *

ws = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(
    per_type_occupancies=True,
    eliminate_cell_deformation=True)
ws.reference.load("../../../WS_Ref/ws.dump")


def modify(frame, input, output):
    occupancies = input.particle_properties['Occupancy'].array

    site_type = input.particle_properties.particle_type.array

    total_occupancy = np.sum(occupancies, axis=1)  # you are also not using, also not using the frame parameter

    selection1 = (site_type == 1) & (occupancies[:, 0] == 0) & (occupancies[:, 1] == 0)

    output.attributes['Ca_Vac'] = np.count_nonzero(selection1)


import glob

for file in glob.glob('../*.glob'):
    node = import_file(file, multiple_frames=True)
    node.modifiers.append(ws)
    node.modifiers.append(PythonScriptModifier(function=modify))
    export_file(
        node, "defects_200.txt", "txt",
        columns=['Timestep', 'Ca_Vac'],
        multiple_frames=True
    )
```

Without knowing more this is the best I could come up with, I hope it works!

Adding this part as per the OP's request.

```
for index, file in enumerate(glob.glob('../*.glob')):
    node = import_file(file, multiple_frames=True)
    node.modifiers.append(ws)
    node.modifiers.append(PythonScriptModifier(function=modify))
    export_file(
        node, "defects_{}.txt".format(index), "txt",
        columns=['Timestep', 'Ca_Vac'],
        multiple_frames=True
    )
```

And again, this is a guess on how the library works and would work only if the original code produces `defetcs_200.txt` as the result.

Comment: seems like no output script is being generated, im guessing maybe its not finding any files to load or something? Instead of *.glob, shouldn't it be *.dump?

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry, it is about 7 am here, yes it is *.dump.

Comment: Ok thanks, I do have a follow up question. It creates a single column of data, is there a way for it to create a new column for each new dump file?

Comment: That sounds more like a complete new question as it is related to the libraries it uses which unfortunately I don't. Sorry.

Comment: Well it only creates one column of data, it seems like it overwrites each old file. There are 1000 rows in the output file, which would correspond to only one dump file

Comment: If the columns are the columns inside the `columns=['Timestep', 'Ca_Vac']`, you can add an enumerate to glob and add that to column strings making numbered columns I guess.

Comment: yeah those are the 2 columns it provides, but only for a single dump file

Comment: Again, I don't know what provides those columns, how can you create new columns in the libraries you use?

Comment: So my original file computes the 2 columns and then outputs them in the txt file. I was hoping to have ~60 columns of data in the single txt file is my point. It loops through all dump files and adds a new column of data. Or is there a way to write a new txt file for each dump file iterated through?

Comment: Again because I didn't use the library you are using I can only guess but it seems like `"defects_200.txt"` is the file it writes to, if so; you can again enumerate the glob and add the values to this string changing it every time, making new files for every dump.

Comment: yeah, im not sure how to do that

Comment: It creates several files, so that is good! But I was wondering, why are the produced files not in numerical order? i would expect  defects_0.txt to correspond to defects_002eV.dump (the lowest number), but it doesnt. Im not sure what numbering method it loads the files in. any guesses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179950/discussion-between-isik-kaplan-and-jackson-hart).

Answer (score 0):

Try python glob package.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```